# How to use Date in Hybris Flexible Search Query?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to fetch records from hybris using Flexible Search query based on date. I tried to find some resources for the same but none worked out.

Basically, I am trying to find products where modified date is equals to the current date.

My current query is:

```
Select * from {product as p} where to_char({p.modifiedDate},'dd/mm/yyyy')==to_char('18/04/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

This is my current query.
However, when I run this using HAC, it give me error:

```
xception message: ORA-00936: missing expression
Exception stacktrace:
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776) oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 4):

As alain.janinm said

1. modifiedtime instead of modifiedDate
2. = instead of ==
3. I guess you do not need the second to_char because it is already char.

Here is official documentation with Oracle and MySQL examples:

- v5 : [FlexibleSearch Tips and Tricks](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/FlexibleSearch+Tips+and+Tricks)
- v6 : [FlexibleSearch Tips and Tricks](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8bc36ba986691014b48be171221d1f4f.html)

Comment: thanks @doom123 . One more thing. Can I use current date in the query for comparison ?

Comment: @AppleBud
Oracle has SYSDATE for current datetime (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm). MySQL has NOW(), CURDATE(). Do not have Oracle to test but with MySQL it worked. OR if you run the query from code then you can form Date string in code directly to insert it into the query. Keep in mind that hybris server and DB server may have different timezones. So DB SYSDATE can give not what your hybris server wants.

Comment: @doom123 - I copied the SQL gen'd from my flex query from logs and ran it  in HAC it seemed fine, but not during runtime. Any idea why this discrepancy ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues :

You use `==` to test equality, using one is enough.

You use `p.modifiedDate` but the field is called `modifiedtime`.

The last to_char call is useless.

Unfortunately I can test with an Orale Db but the Flexible search should looks like :

```
SELECT * from {Product as p} where to_char({p.modifiedTime},'dd/mm/yyyy')='18/04/2017'
```

Comment: thanks @alain.janinm. Can you help in how to use sysdate in that rather than specifying hard coded date ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query as its working for me to fetch the data between two dates:

```
Select {paymentdate} from {PaymentTransaction} where ({paymentdate}  >= '2020/01/01 00:00:01' AND {paymentdate} <= '2021/01/01 00:00:01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```sql
{p.modifiedTime} BETWEEN TO_DATE('18/04/2017 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        AND TO_DATE('18/04/2017 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: the date string and date pattern do not match, have you tested this?